# Design Patterns question

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, reflection

I have a following problem I want to solve ellegantly:

```
public interface IMyclass
{
} 
public class A
{
   public void Init(IMyclass class){?}
   public IMyclass CreateMyClass(){?}
}
```

At the start of the system I want to define dynamic type of IMyClass by using Init() and during the run of the system i would like to create new instances of the type I defined at init.


Notes:

1. IMyclass must be interface

2. The dynamic type of IMyclass known only at init (i have no constructor after :) )

3. I could do it using a reflection or definition method clone at IMyclass is there any better solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to take note that your coding conventions are non-standard.  I for interface declarations and caps for a method are not typically used in Java.  (Some will argue the interface one, but Eclipse is the only major bit of code I have ever seen it used in).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a *provider* into `class A`

```
public class A
{ 
   IMyClassProvider _provider;

   public void Init(IMyClassProvider provider) 
   {
        _provider = provider; 
   }

   public IMyclass CreateMyClass()
   {
        return _provider.Create();
   }
}
```

Or maybe with a constructor delegate

```
public class A
{ 
   Func<IMyclass> _ctor;

   public void Init(Func<IMyclass> ctor) 
   {
        _ctor = ctor; 
   }

   public IMyclass CreateMyClass()
   {
        return _ctor();
   }
}
```

Note that both of these examples will blow up if `Init` has not been called before `CreateMyClass`, you would need some checking or better is doing your init in the constructor.

Have I understood the question correctly?

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by provider or supply usage code?

Comment: I'm just leaving work, will update later if you haven't solved it by then

Comment: I just realised that your question is tagged as Java and I have answered using C# code. It should be possible to apply similar patterns in Java but I'm not so familiar with the syntax.

Comment: I understood that :) but your solution is language independent at java you have Command pattern for delegation. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is a kind of **dependency injection**, you should read:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection
- http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#FormsOfDependencyInjection

Basically, you have a class `A` that is populated with factories (or providers) at initialization. Then you use `A` instead of calling `new`.

A quick example:

```
interface Provider<V> {
   V instance(Object... args);
}
class Dispatch {
   // you can make a singleton out of this class
   Map<Class, Provider> map;
   <T> void register(Class<T> cl, Provider<? extends T> p) {
      // you can also bind to superclasses of cl
      map.put(cl, p);
   }
   <T, I extends T> void register(Class<T> cl, final Class<I> impl) {
      register(cl, new Provider<I>() {
         I instance(Object... args) {
            // this class should be refactored and put in a separate file
            // a constructor with arguments could be found based on types of args values
            // moreover, exceptions should be handled
            return impl.newInstace();
         }
      });
   }
   <T> T instance(Class<T> cl, Object... args) {
      return map.get(cl).instance(args);
   }
}

// usage
interface MyIf { ... }
class MyIfImpl implements MyIf { ... }

Dispatch d = new Dispatch();
d.register(MyIf.class, new Provider<MyIf>() {
   MyIf instance(Object... args) {
      return new MyIfImpl();
   }
});
// or just
d.register(MyIf.class, MyIfImpl.class);
MyIf i = d.instance(MyIf.class);
```

---

Edit:
 added `register(Class, Class)`

Comment: Thank you very much, you have an excelent solution for this problem and i learned form it a lot but I would like to avoid using reflection.

Comment: If you want to do it without reflection, just drop the function `register(Class, Class)`, it may be handy, but isn't quite type-safe.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to instantiate the same class in `CreateMyClass()` without further configuration you can use reflection.

```
public class A
{
    private Class prototype;

    public void Init(IMyClass object) {
        this.prototype = object.getClass();
    }

    public IMyClass CreateMyClass() {
        return prototype.newInstance();
    }
}
```

I suspect you want more than this, and if so you'll need to explain how you want to use this. You may be looking for the [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) or [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) patterns.

Comment: Thank you this solves the problem. But can you tell me what about the performance issue - this parameter I create very frequently. If it could cause performance issue do you have any solution without involving reflection?

Comment: If you want to dynamically instantiate objects based on the class of another at runtime, no. But if you will have only a handful of such classes to do this for you may as well write individual factories for each class fearofawhackplanet demonstrated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need Reflection at some point due to visibility.  If you can accept Reflection once up-front and not have to use it again, that would probably be ideal, yes?

You could put a `getInstance()` method on a hidden interface (located in the same package as `IMyClass`, `MyClassImpl`, and `A`, but not `ClientOfA`), and then pass a prototype of `MyClassImpl` to `A.init()`.

```
// -- You wish you would have thought of the word prototypeable! ...maybe?
interface IMyClassPrototypeable extends IMyClass
{
 public IMyClass getInstance();
}

class MyClassImpl implements IMyClassPrototypeable // -- and IMyClass by extension.
{
 // -- Still not visible outside this package.
 public IMyClass getInstance()
 {
  return new MyClassImpl();
 }
}

class A
{
 private IMyClassPrototypeable prototype;

 // -- This method is package-private.
 void init( IMyClassPrototypeable prototype )
 {
  this.prototype = prototype;
 }

 public IMyClass createMyClass()
 {
  return prototype.getInstance();
 }
}
```

This solution would require Reflection to create the prototype instance of `MyClassImpl`, which could be done via Spring (or some other form of dependency injection).  It uses the Prototype pattern, the Factory-method pattern, and readily supports the Singleton/Pool pattern, but remember that more design patterns used is not always better.  In fact, it can make the design (and code) more complex and more difficult for a beginner to understand.

For the record, the only reason I would even think about advocating this solution is because it takes the reflection hit once, up front, rather than every time `createMyClass()` is called, which the original poster indicated he/she would be doing frequently.